# Каков правовой статус Правил орфографии и пунктуации 1956 года и ПАС под ред. Лопатина?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, правила

Согласно **Федеральному закону** о государственном языке РФ от 2005 года (с изменениями 2020 года)  **Правительство РФ** на основании рекомендаций Правительственной **комиссии** по русскому языку утверждает **список грамматик, словарей и справочников**, содержащих **нормы** современного русского литературного языка при его использовании в качестве государственного языка РФ (**по результатам экспертизы**), а также **правила русской орфографии и пунктуации**.

В 2009 году был  утвержден список словарей, грамматик и справочников, содержащих нормы языка (всего 4 позиции): "Орфографический словарь русского языка" Букчиной, Сазоновой, Чельцовой, "Грамматический словарь русского языка" под редакцией Андрея Зализняка, "Словарь ударений русского языка" Резниченко и "Большой фразеологический словарь русского языка" В. Телия.

А какие решения еще были приняты,  как насчет других словарей и справочников, а главное, что известно о Правилах орфографии и пунктуации Розенталя и ПАС под ред. Лопатина?  **Они были утверждены, какой правовой статус они имеют сейчас?**

Этот вопрос чисто практического характера. Редакции этих правил имеют **много отличий**, какими нормами в этих случаях нужно пользоваться?

Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за ваше мнение. Я еще немного поискала в Интернете и нашла информацию, которая мне показалась достаточно убедительной. https://philol.msu.ru/~ruslang/siencework/discussionclub/?page=rules2006  С другой стороны, хотелось бы услышать что-либо новое на эту тему.